# EXCEL automatically get the equivalent based on table

Tags: excel

Inside sheet 1, there is this table which has the rank and level with its corresponding point values.

[image]

and in my sheet 2, I have this table.

[image]

**How to automatically get the corresponding point value from the table 1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=iferror(INDEX(SHEET1!$B$2:$E$5,match(sheet2!$C6,SHEET1!$A$2:$A$5,0),sheet2!$D6),"")
```

The iferror will return "" for when you dont have a match or you have a faulty level grater than the number of columns in your table.

the match will return the row you want to look in, and the level itself will tell you what column to look in.  Index will return the cell at the intersection of those two points within its range specified in this case as SHEET1!B2:E5

Comment: saw an error but I figured it out. `=IFERROR(INDEX(sheet1!$B$2:$E$5,MATCH(sheet2!$C6,sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,0),sheet2!$D6),"")`

Comment: @quickbrownfox Dang it I kept meaning to go back and add the sheet reference in.  Mind you that also means you don't need all the sheet2 references since you are using the formula on sheet2!